# Google Cloud Platform - App Engine

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine

quisiera saber si alguien a configurado en un proyecto de **App Engine** alguno de estos:
- nginx-http.conf
- nginx-app.conf
- nginx.conf
Configure el **nginx-http.conf** dentro de mi proyecto de esta manera:
client_max_body_size 100M;
proxy_read_timeout 1800;
proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
proxy_send_timeout 1800;
send_timeout 1800;
fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
Y hice deploy, pero no lo toma en cuenta, agredeceria sus comentarios saludos!!!

Comment: estas usando flex o standard?

Comment: estoy usando flex

Answer (score 0):

En App Engine como es un sistema manejado hay cosas que no se pueden editar, y estos valores entran en ese grupo.

client_max_body_size está limitado a 32 MB en caso de necesitar más la misma documentación de Google nos sugiere [utilizar la Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/).

En el caso de los timeouts ese está determinado por el tippo de Instancia y del *scaling* que uses.

En el caso de Flex es de 1 hora, y en el caso de standard dependiendo de el tipo de *scaling*  para automático es de 10 minutos mientras que para scaling básico o manual es de hasta un día.